# Setting material in Unity in run time issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I change material in runtime with this it does not work

```
expoSceneLarge.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0] = availableMaterials[selectedMaterialIndex];
```

however using this

```
expoSceneLarge.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = availableMaterials[selectedMaterialIndex];
```

material is being changed in run time.
What confuses me is that material, according to Unity return the first element in materials attached to renderer, so why materials[0] does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
I has to create new array of materials, change the once I was interested in and the assign whole array to mesh renderer. Here is a a full code for future reference.

```
var newMaterials = new Material[_expoMaterials.Count()];

        for(int i = 0; i < newMaterials.Count(); i++)
        {
          // i = 1 for floor
          if(i == 1)
          {
            newMaterials[i] = availableMaterials[selectedMaterialIndex];
          }
          else
          {
            newMaterials[i] = _expoMaterials[i];
          }

        }

        expoSceneLarge.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials = newMaterials;
```